# Is there a way to wipe out my iPhone data programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, itunes

I just want to wipe out my iPhone data programatically.Can anybody help me ?

Comment: just prompt the user with an alert message "it is now safe to put your phone in the microwave", should do the trick

Comment: You can destroy only what you've created!